# How do I replace <br/> with space at the end of the string? and How do I order a list using the indexes of other array

Tags: javascript

Need a JavaScript regular expression to remove only one break tag at the end of the string.

Example:

Input:  `Sample br/ string that needs to remove br/ at the end br/ br/`

Output: `Sample br/ string that needs to remove br/ at the end br/`

Need to order a list using the index of other array.

ex:
  MyList[0] {name: abc, value:10, id : 2} 
  MyList[1] {name: ghf, value:123, id : 1} 
  MyList[1] {name: ghjs, value:12, id : 4} 
  MyList[1] {name: lhjsk, value:13, id : 5}

here the id value is stored in the below array. I need to order based on the below array order.

Arrayids[4, 1, 2 , 5]

Output:
 MyList[1] {name: ghjs, value:12, id : 4} 
 MyList[1] {name: ghf, value:123, id : 1} 
 MyList[0] {name: abc, value:10, id :2} 
 MyList[1] {name: lhjsk, value:13, id : 5}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex builder to test regex easily. Check this regex here: [regexr.com/4bv9f](http://regexr.com/4bv9f)

```js
let string = "Sample br/ string that needs to remove br/ at the end br/ br/",
regex = /br\/$/,
result = string.replace(regex, '');
console.log('From:',string);
console.log('To:',result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a regular expression but you could remove the last line break with `str.slice(0, -n)` where n is the number of characters you want to remove from your string (3 in the case of removing `br/`).

Answer (score 0):

To remove the last **br/** at the end of the string you can use thr slice method of javascript. Below is the solution:

```
 var str = 'Sample br/ string that needs to remove br/ at the end br/ br/'
 var str1 = str.slice(0, str.length -3);
```

The output will be as you have expected:

**Sample br/ string that needs to remove br/ at the end br/**